# Нахождение времени столкновения двух объектов в пространстве

Tags: python, геометрия, координаты, уравнения

Мне необходимо найти время когда столкнутся два объекта в пространстве. Один движется по окружности, другой по прямой. Мне дана нормаль к плоскости, где движется первый объект, центр окружности, начальная точка первого объекта, угловая скорость и скорость движения второго объекта. Второй объект начинает движение из начала координат.

```
x = P-C # P - нач. точка, C - центр окружности
R = np.linalg.norm(x)
y = np.cross(N, x)
y = y / np.linalg.norm(y)  * R

def intersection_point(t):
    orbital_position = C + x * np.cos(omega * t) + y * np.sin(omega * t)

    probe_position = V * t * (orbital_position / np.linalg.norm(orbital_position))

    return np.linalg.norm(orbital_position - probe_position)

time_of_intersection = fsolve(intersection_point, 1)[0]
```

Есть вот такой код, но мне нужно улучшить точность решения, чтобы правильно определить координаты столкновения (каждая из них с точностью до 5 знаков)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150301/discussion-on-question-by-qaqan------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Для увеличения точности решения и определения координат столкновения с точностью до 5 знаков рекомендую воспользоваться методом оптимизации и стандартными математическими вычислениями.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Данные параметры
C = np.array([C_x, C_y, C_z])  # центр окружности
P = np.array([P_x, P_y, P_z])  # начальная точка первого объекта
N = np.array([N_x, N_y, N_z])  # нормаль к плоскости, где движется первый объект
omega = 1.0  # угловая скорость движения первого объекта
V = np.array([V_x, V_y, V_z])  # скорость движения второго объекта

# Расчет точки пересечения с использованием метода оптимизации
def intersection_criteria(t):
    x = P - C
    R = np.linalg.norm(x)
    y = np.cross(N, x)
    y = y / np.linalg.norm(y) * R
    orbital_position = C + x * np.cos(omega * t) + y * np.sin(omega * t)
    probe_position = V * t * (orbital_position / np.linalg.norm(orbital_position))
    return np.linalg.norm(orbital_position - probe_position)

# Функция для минимизации
def objective_function(t):
    return intersection_criteria(t)

# Начальная догадка для минимизации
initial_guess = 1.0

# Минимизация с использованием метода оптимизации
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, method='TNC', options={'xtol': 1e-5, 'disp': False})

# Получение времени столкновения
time_of_intersection = result.x[0]

# Вычисление координат столкновения
orbital_position_at_intersection = C + (P - C) * np.cos(omega * time_of_intersection) + np.cross(N, P - C) * np.sin(omega * time_of_intersection)
probe_position_at_intersection = V * time_of_intersection

# Вывод результатов с округлением до 5 знаков
print("Координаты столкновения:")
print("Орбитальная позиция:", np.round(orbital_position_at_intersection, 5))
print("Позиция зонда:", np.round(probe_position_at_intersection, 5))
```